# Recover system gcc on linux

Tags: linux, gcc

I was trying to install manually `gcc` and forgot to specify `--prefix=`. So, after `make install` binaries were installed on standard paths (like `/usr/bin/` or smth.) And now as I type `gcc --version` it responds `gcc 6.0.0`. How can I return my system gcc back which I had after installing my fedora 20?

Comment: GCC 6 is not yet released, and still is being worked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile a pristine [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) from source [downloaded](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) from its site, the default prefix is `/usr/local/`, not `/usr/`.

Use `which gcc` to understand  what `gcc` is in your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) then try `gcc -v`; then use `echo $PATH` to understand the current setting of your `PATH`

So your gcc is `/usr/local/bin/gcc` but the system gcc is still `/usr/bin/gcc`

(In some Linux distributions, e.g. Debian, `/usr/bin/gcc` is an indirect symbolic link to e.g. `/usr/bin/gcc-4.9` thru `/etc/alternatives/gcc`; I don't know what Fedora is doing)

So just set up your `PATH` (probably in your `~/.bashrc`) so that `/usr/bin/` is before (or after, if you so wishes) `/usr/local/bin/`

I even have two shell functions `local_before_path` and `local_after_path` which are switching between the two possibilities.

You should probably be able to reinstall the system GCC, perhaps with `yum reinstall gcc` or some similar command. On some distributions (Debian notably) you can have *several* versions of system GCC (e.g. `gcc-4.8` and `gcc-4.9`)

Next time you compile GCC 5.2 (mid-july 2015) from its [released](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) source code pass both `--prefix=/usr/local/` and `--program-suffix=-mine` to its `../gcc-5.2/configure` script. You'll get `gcc-mine` in `/usr/local/bin/` !

Comment: Bad news (for me): `which` responds `/usr/bin/gcc`. `/usr/local/bin/` is empty.

Comment: Yes, `yum gcc reinstall` was actually the solution.